# Unity3d SimpleJSON add int to JSONClass

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I'm using [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) for Unity3d. And i want to add `int` to `JSONClass`.

For example i need json : `{"attr" : 4}`

```
JSONClass cl = new JSONClass();
```

I tried this:

```
cl["attr"].AsInt = 4;
```

And this:

```
cl["attr"] = new JSONData(4);
```

And any other cases. Anyway i get `{"attr" : "4"}` where `4` is string.

How can i add `int` to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In current realization it's not possible.

So i added new types:

```
public enum JSONBinaryTag
    {
        Array            = 1,
        Class            = 2,
        Value            = 3,
        IntValue        = 4,
        DoubleValue        = 5,
        BoolValue        = 6,
        FloatValue        = 7,
        LongValue         = 8,
        String          = 9,   // <-- new
        Number = 10           // <-- new
    }
```

And add type checking in JSONData:

```
public class JSONData : JSONNode{
    static Regex m_Regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?$");
    private JSONBinaryTag m_Type = JSONBinaryTag.String;

    private string m_Data;
    public override string Value {
        get { return m_Data; }
        set { m_Data = value; } 
    }
    public JSONData(string aData){
        m_Data = aData;

        // check for number
        if (m_Regex.IsMatch(m_Data))
            m_Type = JSONBinaryTag.Number;
        else
            m_Type = JSONBinaryTag.String;

    }
    [...]
}
```

And changed `toString()` method:

```
   public override string ToString(){
        if (m_Type == JSONBinaryTag.String)
            return "\"" + Escape(m_Data) + "\"";
        else
            return Escape(m_Data);

    }
```

Now `int`, `float`, `double` will be added as number without `"`. And will look something like this: `{"attr" : 4}`

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this? https://gist.github.com/lcnvdl/4532671a8f4dbbb6f306

To use just do:

```
JsonHelper.Json(myObject);
```

You can use it with objects, GameObjects, ScriptableObjects, MonoBehaviour, etc.

Comment: I think it's slower 'cause of reflection.